# Alert Notification in asp.net c# through loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, alert, toast

How to display an alert box in UI from code behind through for loop?

I have a function that processes data from the CSV file and writes logs into the database. I also want to show a notification or alert in the UI so that I can know instantly what's happening in the system. I tried toast notification and alert but it only displays once after the loop finished.

Here is my code:

```
 AddLog(finalJobId, taskId, "Sending batch to Payment Gateway # of Records:" + JobCount + " from" + txtCSVFile.Text);
                for (int i = 0; i < JobCount; i++)
                {
                    var items = csvLists[i];
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", "The Payment is being proceed for : " + items["First Name"] + " " + items["Last Name"]));
                    var paymentId = items["Payment Id"];
                    var clientId = items["Client Id"];
                    var client = items["Client Name"];
                    var amount = items["Total Payment Amount"];
                    var method = items["Payment Method"];
                    AddLog(finalJobId, taskId, "Sending payment #" + i + "- Client: " + client + " - PaymentId: " + paymentId + " -  Amount: " + amount + " - Payment Method: " + method);
                                
                    //Process Actual Payment Options with Details
                    var task = ProcessPayment.Process(int.Parse(clientId), int.Parse(paymentId), serverValue);
                    AddLog(finalJobId, taskId, "Received Response  #" + i + " - Client: " + client + " - PaymentId: " + paymentId + " -  Amount: " + amount + " - Payment Method: " + method + " - Result: " + task.Result.Response);

                }
                AddLog(finalJobId, taskId, "Completed batch for Payment Request # of Records:" + JobCount);
```

I usually have more than 200 records in the CSV file, so I have to wait for a while after process a payment. I don't know what is the best way to shows a notification so that users will understand what is happening at the moment.

Comment: you'll need to use signalR to display progress on the client side.

Comment: @JoelFleischman Can you please show me how to use that signalR in my context. I don't know how it works actually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the most easy way to figure this out?

Well, when you click on a button, the page (post back) is sent to the server.

You code runs - and all code behind is BLOCKED until it is done.(you can NOT make additional calls from that web page. The web page is sitting "stuck" on server side land, waiting for code to finish.

When code does finally finish, the page is sent BACK down to the client side.

So, obviously this line of code can't work:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage" bla bla
```

Since, after above, the long delay code runs. ONLY AFTER that long running code is finished, then does the code stub finish, and THEN the WHOLE PAGE is sent back down to the client. (including the above idea of wanting to run some js - that will only start running after the page is sent down BACK to the client side.

So, there are as many ways to do this as their are flavors of ice cream, but the MOST simple?

Well, whatever button they click on that starts your above code simply has to show your toast message client side BEFORE the post back.

Thus, you pop up the toast, and THEN your code behind runs. We don't even have to write code to dismiss/hide/close/remove the message, since when the page comes rolling down back down the pipe to the browser?

Well the whole page is re-loaded for you in the client, and thus your toast message will go away.

This is thus the "most" easy. But it does mean the web page is blocked quite much from interaction and we ARE waiting for a whole copy of that page to come zooming down from the server WHEN that long running code is finally finished.

So, super simple:

We assume you have a asp.net button on the form.
We assume the user going to click on that button, and then run your code.
Note that the web page travels back up to the server and THEN your code runs.
The web page is not coming back to client side until that code runs and is done.

As noted, we can use this effect to our advantage.

So, your asp button click can use OnClientClick(). This means that the client side code (js) will run BEFORE your server (code behind runs) on that button click.

And it also runs before the post back to server occurs. (web page travel to server).

So, we use this to display a "div", or fill out a text box, or in your case some toast message.

So, button code will be:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Confirm my order" 
OnClientClick="GoGo2()" />
```

So the above is our lovable standard asp button. But, note the "OnClientClick".
So, it will run both client side and server side events. But it WILL FIRST run the client side code we call (the client side routine called GoGo2()).

That client side routine can thus display the message.
Above calls our client side code stub, say this:

```
<script>

function GoGo2() {

        $.toast({
            heading: "Working",
            text: 'Processing order -  - please wait',
            hideAfter: false,
            position: 'top-right',
            icon: 'info'
        })

    }
</script>
```

Now, of course you could get/grab/pull/use a value of a text box or other controls (client side) to create a "better" message.
So the message could say:

```
heading: "Order #" + $('#txtBoxOrderNum').val(),
text: 'Processing order please wait',
```

Or whatever else you have on that web page. Do note that we can only get/grab/use current values in the web page (no server side values from code behind).

So, now we have this:

User clicks on button.

Above toast message displays (our client side js).

Heck you can display (shove) info in a text box, or even hide/show a "div" and NOT even use toast. But some kind of toast plug in is just fine.

Now that routine runs, displays your message client side.

THEN the web page makes trip up to server. Then your code behind for that button click starts running. When the long running code is done, then the page THEN makes the trip back to the browser.

Because we getting a whole new page back down browser side?

Well then the toast message will be blown out (disappear) and thus we don't need code to update, or hide the message, since we just received a fresh new copy of the web page anyway!

So above is the most easy.

If the process was LONG(er) running, say more then a few seconds, say 25 seconds? Well, you don't want to block up a whole web page for that long. (all other (server side code) and any buttons be frozen.

In that case? Well, then we need to use a thread object and thread out the call to a sperate thread. (it is easy to do).

Now the button click and browser round trip will occur very fast.

However, for status updates, we would have to START that running code AFTER the page comes back client side. (you can try and inject script as you attempted for this idea).

However, its usually better to NOT do a post back if you going to status update the page in the FIRST place.

jQuery.AJAX calls are VERY easy, and you can call web methods on the existing page (no need to setup a web server page (asmx) for this.

In effect if you REALLY want a process update (say % done), or show several messages as the long processing is occurring? We will want to avoid a post back, and avoid post back blockage. One way is to use a update-panel. But your main page will have to thread out the long running process regardless and NOT BE BLOCKED (ever!!!).

I could add a edit to this page to include a jQuery AJAX call, but the above is oh so simple, and I think should suffice fine for this example.

And this approach is super simple - no need to introduce new technology, ajax calls, or signalR concepts.

EVEN if you did/do introduce signalR, then you STILL will have to thread out the long process to ensue that the browser round trip is not blocked.

As noted, in these cases (wanting % status updates etc.), then I REALLY (no, but REALLY REALLY) would not do a post back. So one then would be wise to start the whole process and status updates using a AJAX call.

And since we assume it is most practical to AVOID post back WHEN we want a status update system (% done etc.), then a few simple ajax calls are less work and easier then signalR setup anyway.